# Designing a action history database for different types of actions

Tags: database-design

In a bugtrackingsystem, I want to keep track of some actions. Actions like change status, add comment, change priority, and other actions.

The problem is, how do I store those different actions, with different parameters. For example when someone changes status, it needs to save statuschange, with old status and new status. But when someone adds a comment, it needs to save comment added, with comment id.

One solution could be to save those parameters as plain text. Like "oldstatus => new status", "comment 001 added". But that doesn't seem really viable.

Does someone know how this could work best?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the actual status in the bug table, and keep a history of status changes in a different table:

```
changeid (pk) - ticketid (fk) - date - oldstatus - newstatus - username
```

Comments usually go in a different table too:

```
commentid (pk) - ticketid (fk) - date - username - comment
```

When retrieving data, you can retrieve all comments for a bug like:

```
select 
from comments 
where comments.bugid = 12
```

P.S. (pk) = primary key, (fk) is foreign key

Comment: Status is kept in the table. What I wanted to store is a summary of what is changed in such a way that it's easy to retrieve again later.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer keeping a separate entry in `TaskInfoRevision` table for each change, with all the fields like status, comment, properties, etc., and then determine what has changed in your application code, not in the DB itself.

Comment: Could you explain this some more?